# Cloudera CDH demos

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

Datastax DSE comes with well organized [demos](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/getting_started/doc/getting_started/gsDemos.html). Does `Cloudera CDH5` offer something alike?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Cloudera Quickstart VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html). It (specifically, Hue) contains some demos of using Hadoop. If you just want sample code or writeups online, rather than a live service, just look for anything on the internet. Any Hadoop-related demo will work.

Answer (score 0):

The only demo that Cloudera offers is it's [Cloudera Live](http://go.cloudera.com/cloudera-live.html). And it is still in beta version.

Comment: Erm, the VM is full of demos. http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html

Comment: My bad! :) but you still need to use the VM. Does the VM has description about the demos like in DataStax DSE?

Comment: It's basically the Hue demos: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/new-hue-demos-spark-ui-job-browser-oozie-scheduling-and-yarn-support/ and http://gethue.com/category/tutorial/